# C# - Unable to change ApplicationVersion from MSBuild script

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, office-addins, msbuild-task

I'm a newbie trying to modify on publish the ApplicationVersion value by AssemblyVersion one on a MS Office AddIn.
Here is my csproj :

```
<Target Name="SetAssemblyVersionToPublish" AfterTargets="AfterCompile">
<ReadLinesFromFile File="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<PropertyGroup>
  <In>@(AssemblyVersion)</In>
  <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
  <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
  <ApplicationVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</ApplicationVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="app Version : $(ApplicationVersion)" Importance="High" />
```

When I publish the app from Visual Studio 2015, logs show the good version :

```
app Version : 4.4.9.0
```

But in fact it is the ApplicationVersion defined in VS that is used :

```
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
```

[image: App_1_0_0_0]

I already tried :

- reset all VS settings
- disable any vs third party extensions
- use safemode
- if I publish a WPF app, it works well

Any one would know why I get this change ?

---

**Update**

After some test, I found that MSBUILD use a different target file for VSTO : MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets.
It seems to use PublishVersion which is a copy of ApplicationVersion. I don't know why but if I set ApplicationVersion in my target, it does not update the PublishVersion... If I set the publishVersion, I get the good version in my bin folder, but publishing failed (don't copy to publish folder because it still want to get the folder with 1_0_0_0 in bin).
It may be a problem with a bad step which launch my target, but I don't figure when it must be done.

Any help ?

---

**UPDATE 2**

It seems to be a bug with VS2015 publishing tool. If I try with msbuild.exe command line, it works well:

On VS I get an error asking for the below folder :
[image]

Whereas with the following msbuild command, it works :
MSBuild xxx\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1.csproj /t:clean;publish

Anyone know what can be done as a workaround ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Product Version and File Version to different numbers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113511/set-product-version-and-file-version-to-different-numbers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all**, I have a question, when I use your code in a winform project and execute publish, I got an error like:

[image]

**After I test**, I found that

`ApplicationVersion` which you got is illegal three digits instead of four digits, so there is a problem with your method of obtaining `AssemblyVersion`.

**In general**, the publish version is under Project **Properties**(right-click on your project)-->**Publish**

[image]

You can note that it is four digits.

Which proves that you have miss a node on `Pattern` property.

**Suggestion**

You should use

```
 <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
```

The whole code are:

```
 <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <In>@(AssemblyVersion)</In>
      <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
      <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
      <ApplicationVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="app Version : $(ApplicationVersion)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

It will reads the `AssemblyVersion` from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

**In my side**, it is

[image]

**Actually**, your method already works and it overwrite the publish version for the app.

I think you have read the first part of the build output log like this:

[image]

It is only the default system initial value at the beginning of the build, and it is just displayed there. And then through your custom msbuild script actually has overwritten its value.

[image]

**Before** executing publish, you should delete the `publish` folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then execute the **publish**, you can enter the folder to check:

[image]

[image]

**Update 1**

I think your csproj file has imported some targets or props file which has other targets overwrite the `AfterCompile` target. So your method failed.

That is, your method may be overwritten elsewhere.

So I think you should not use AfterCompile as the target name and should name it as another to distinguish between them.

Use this:

```
<Target Name="SetAssemblyVersionToPublish" AfterTargets="AfterCompile">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <In>@(AssemblyVersion)</In>
      <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
      <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
      <ApplicationVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="app Version : $(ApplicationVersion)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

**Or**, You can add a file called `Directory.Build.targets` file on your project folder
and then add my code on it:

[image]

```
 <Project>
    <Target Name="SetAssemblyVersionToPublish" AfterTargets="AfterCompile">
        <ReadLinesFromFile File="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
          <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
        </ReadLinesFromFile>
        <PropertyGroup>
          <In>@(AssemblyVersion)</In>
          <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
          <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
          <ApplicationVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</ApplicationVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="app Version : $(ApplicationVersion)" Importance="High" />
      </Target>
  </Project>
```

**Then**, delete `bin`, `obj`, `publish` folder and then republish again to check it.

If the issue still persists, you should try the following suggestions to troubleshoot the issue:

**1)** Try to reset vs settings by **Tools**-->**Import and Export settings**-->**Reset all vs settings**

**2)** disable any vs third party extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates** -->**Installed**, after that, close VS ,restart your project.

**3)** you could try [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) on the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 to start a pure, initial vs to test your solution.

===============================================

**Update 2**

The **MS Office Excel AddIn** project is quite different from the traditional projects. And it is impossible by using this way.

**As a workaround**, I think you should use msbuild script to publish the project.

**1)** create a file called `PublishExcel.proj`

**2)** add these content on that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Target Name="SetAssemblyVersionToPublish">
<!--you must specify the full path of the AssemblyInfo.cs from your project -->
<ReadLinesFromFile File="C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"> 
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<PropertyGroup>
  <In>@(AssemblyVersion)</In>
  <Pattern>\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).(\d+)</Pattern>
  <Out>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</Out>
  <ApplicationVersion>$(Out.Remove(0, 28))</ApplicationVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="app Version : $(ApplicationVersion)" Importance="High" />

<MSBuild Projects="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1.csproj" Properties="ApplicationVersion=$(ApplicationVersion)" Targets="Publish">
   </MSBuild>
</Target>
</Project>
```

**3)** then open Developer Command prompt for VS2015 and then type:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx\PublishExcel.proj -t:SetAssemblyVersionToPublish
```

**And** the publish folder will be under the bin\Debug or Release\app.publish folder.

This function will work for MS Office Excel AddIn project.

Comment: It should not be what you showed. Maybe there are something wrong. Please check my answer and I have updated it. Please check it.

Comment: I did all you suggest, I still have the same behaviour (even in safemode). Is there any way to debug step by step the publishing process ?

Comment: you have only to check the detailed build,publish log by `Tools`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run`-->set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed` to get the detailed log. There maybe something wrong with your vs environment or project. Please try to create a new project and then test the code again to check whether the issue persists on the new one. If it still persists, please repair vs2015 under control panel-->Programs--> right-click on  vs2015 and select `Change` and then click Repair.

Comment: Or you could share your project sample with us to help us troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I just create step by step  from scratch the app. One thing I forgot is that the published project is not a WPF but a MS Office Excel AddIn... If I publish the WPF it works well, but not for the AddIn. I'll look at difference between both app.

Comment: Yes it seems to work (even without creating the proj file by using msbuild on the csproj file). For my understanding : why does it works with msbuild and not with VS publish ?

Comment: actually, yes, that is the same result. And I check that you used a target to read the the info from the `assemblyinfo.cs` file. So I suggest that you used a msbuild script. And It seems that you used `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:publish -p:ApplicationVersion=x.x.x.x`.

Comment: I updated my info with the command I use :  MSBuild xxx\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1.csproj /t:clean;publish. Any idea why it works with msbuild and not with VS ?

Comment: The issue is the project itself. Actually, if you set `<ApplicationVersion>4.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>`, this proeprty will be read before executing the build process. And the issue is that this project will only read the property before the build process start. However, other projects such wpf, winform do not acts the same result.

Comment: If you uses a target to change the value of the property, it is under the build process. So the project will always uses the defaults value or the value like `<ApplicationVersion>4.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>`(before the build process) and cannot get the modified value during the build process. I think it is a special feature for this ExcelAddIn project. The solution is that you can transmit the modified value before msbuild call the build process.

Comment: So you should use [msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019) and transmit the value before execute the build process. That why I suggest you should use a msbuild script. The goal of it is to make the modified value of ApplicationVersion run before the msbuild task.

Comment: First, reads all the global property on the proj file. Then execute the build process, execute the related targets. However, `ExcelAddIn` projects only get the value on the global property or at the beginning. like  `<PropertyGroup><ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion></PropertyGroup>`. You can try to use `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:publish -p:ApplicationVersion=x.x.x.x`. This is also set a new changed value for `ApplicationVersion` before executing the build process.